# Convert an array of keys into an object of key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I know how to convert this:

```
const keys = [1, 2, 3];
```

To this:

```
[{key: 1, val: "q"}, {key: 2, val: "w"}, {key: 3, val: "e"}]
```

With a single mapping statement:

```
keys.map((x, i) => ({key: x, val: "qwe".charAt(i)}));
```

But I would actually like to get this:

```
{1: "q", 2: "w", 3: "e"}
```

Is there a neat way to do this in a single statement similar to the one above?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].reduce((p, c, i) => (p[c] = "qwe"[i], p), {});`, alternative: `Object.fromEntries([1, 2, 3].map((e, i) => [e, "qwe"[i]]));`

Comment: @ASDFGerte: Hmmm... that's even neater than the one I just found myself. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ASDFGerte: Was referring to your first (original) suggestion.

Comment: yeah, just writing some ways that come to mind. You already showed `Object.assign`, so i think we got all the common ways. Wonder if there are some unfeasible but fun ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
keys.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => { accumulator[index] = "qwe".charAt(index); return accumulator; }, {})
```

Comment: `var a = (b) => b = 10` so `a(5)` returns  10

Comment: If someone notices you of your code not working, you could at least check by testing it, cause then you would see, that it actually doesnt. Instead of asking stuff that won't benefit anyone.

Comment: I really didn't tested, but your comment is not the reason of not work. I'm just explaining it to you. I'm writing from mobile, so can't test it

Comment: Assignments yield the right side value, which in your case is a character (string), and will mess up the next step of `reduce` completely. You need to return the actual object, as mentioned, as shown in my comment, and another answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203057/discussion-between-elias-soares-and-asdfgerte).

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, got it:

```
const objects = Object.assign({}, ...keys.map((x, i) => ({[x]: "qwe".charAt(i)})));
```

Though I would be happy to hear other suggestions as well as any notes on this one...

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce, and empty object as the initial value for the accumulator and insert property-value pairs on it:

```js
const keys = [1, 2, 3];

let result = keys.reduce((obj, key, idx) => { obj[key] = 'qwe'[idx]; return obj }, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```js
const keys = [1, 2, 3];
const vals = "qwe";
const result = keys.reduce((prev, cur, idx) => ({
    ...prev,
    [cur]: vals[idx]
}), {});
```